# I’m trying to generate a standalone exe file from multiple python files and additional files (image, excel spreadsheet)

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm quite new to programming with Python so I might be missing something quite obvious here.

I've done a small program in Python which runs ok, but I wanted to share it with my colleagues so I thought of doing a standalone version of it, I've tried using Pyinstaller as it seems the easiest and more straightforward to use, but the exe file generated doesn't seem to work so far.

So I have my program divided in a main file called "main.py" and 3 extra functions that I import in main from other python files in the same folder. It uses one excel spreadsheet and one .ico image for the logo in tkinter.

My first try has been using just the command:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

It generates the exe file, but when executing it it just opens a black window and nothing else happens.

I was reading the documentation for pyinstaller and thought I might need to add the other python files too and the extra files. For the excel and the image I didn't manage to understand how I need to write it, I tried to add the following as options, but it gave me back an error

```
--add-data <logo.ico> --add-data <WAE_SW_NameCnvtn.xlsx>
```

Without those, I managed to generate again the exe file using the following command:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --name=NameCnvtn main.py read_description.py read_quantity.py word_finder.py
```

This seemed to add quite a few more files to the dist folder, and when I execute the exe file instead of the black window it says "failed to execute the script main", which I assume referes to my main.py file.

In case it helps, I developed it using python 3.6.4 and it uses tkinter and openpyxl.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @J Berjano and welcome to Stack Overflow. Great job at explaining the steps you have taken so far. Can I suggest you edit your question to make a bit clearer exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Your question title hints at that but it would be great if you could tell us explicitly what you are hoping to achieve, in the question.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the title, hope is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to successfully run the exe today. I manually added in the spec file the excel and the ico under the data line, compiled it again and it was running correctly after that. here is the spec file in case someone has the same problem as I had.

```html
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py', 'read_description.py', 'read_quantity.py', 'word_finder.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\j.berjano\\Desktop\\app_test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('WAE_SW_NameCnvtn.xlsx','.'),('logo.ico','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='NameCnvtn',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
    icon='logo.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='NameCnvtn')
```

Comment: and how do you run this?  I'm in the same situation here. I've got a project and when I used pyinstaller  I've only got one prompt screen that runs once and doesn't actually open the program interface. can you explain this script a bit?